# Git commit followed by checkout

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

I just started using git so this may sound like a dumb question, sorry about that.

I am developing in python and using Pycharm on windows 7. I am using the pycharm interface to execute git commands.

After working on some branch, I committed my changes (but not pushed them). After that, I checked out master, and then checked out the same branch again. But it was not the same as when I committed. Can I go back to the version that I committed?

Again, please bare in mind that I am a beginner when responding.

Comment: What you're describing doesn't sound right.  Can you specify the commands you used throughout the above process?

Comment: How do you know the branch is different to before checking out master? What's the difference and what did you expect to see?

Comment: I am using pycharm community addition 2016.1.3. In the bottom of the screen on the right side there is an interface which allows you to checkout branches. I checked out master, and then the same branch that I did the commit to before. Now I have some missing files.

Comment: Maybe I should point again that I only committed my changes locally, I did not push them.

Comment: ```git reflog``` should be able to tell you where you have been

Comment: "I have some missing files" do you mean that git reports that files are missing? Or git reports no uncommitted changes, but you expected some files to exist and it's not there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s impossible. There are some conditions which may cause you can not find the commit after checkout, such as you were working on detached HEAD or you were working on another branch.

To figure it out, you can use the command `git reflog` to find latest message from top to down:

```
checkout: moving from *** to master at HEAD@{n}
```

- If the `***` shows a branch name like:

  `5cc0787 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from dev to master`

  That means before you checkout to `master` branch, you committed change on `dev` branch.
- If the `***` shows a commit id (sha-1 value) like:

  `5cc0787 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from b503fa537bac459862752641facbd5b50783d7b5 to master`

  That means you were work on a detached HEAD statue. And if the committed changes you still want to use for a branch (such as `stage`), you can create a new branch (`temp`) from the detached HEAD (`git checkout -b temp b503f`), and then merge the new created branch `temp` into `stage` (`git checkout stage` and `git merge temp`).